# Difference between ctrl-z and "&" in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

My understanding is that when you are running any command (say `sleep 10`) within a given shell (say bash), what's happening under the hood is that a fork system call is called, and `sleep 10` is now running as a child process with the parent being the bash shell I executed the sleep.

Now, if I want to send `sleep` to the background, I would either do `sleep 10 &` or run `sleep 10` and press ctrl+z so the process is sent to the background. pstree shows that using any of these options, sleep keeps being a child process of the bash shell.

Now my question is, when doing this through SSH, I noted the following:
If I do: `sleep 999 &` and `sleep 888` <- followed by a ctrl+z, and the close the ssh session, only `sleep 999 &` survived.

Why is this? I actually was expecting one of these:

- both processes gets terminated because the parent process is gone
- both processes gets associated to init as the parent process.

Comment: Are you __sure__ you are using bash?

Comment: Ctrl+Z stops a foreground job. Unless you resume it, it will be a stopped job, not a background job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> or run sleep 10 and press ctrl+z so the process is sent to the background

No, not really. Didn't you see that big message that says "[1]+ **Stopped** sleep 10"? `ctrl+z` **stops** the process and returns you to the current shell. You can now type `fg` to continue process, or type `bg` to continue the process in the background. Research "bash job control" and see bash manual Job Control Basics.

> Why is this?

Stopped processes are first continued `SIGCONT` and then `SIGTERM` is sent to them so they can terminate.

Bash manual is available online: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html .